This is the house I live. vs This is the place I live


This is the place I live. (O)




This is the house I live. (X) > This is the house I live in. (O)




This is the place I live in. ?


Q1. Why 1 is correct but 2 is wrong?
Q2. 'the place' in 1 means adverb phrase?(cf. 'the house' is noun phrase)
If adverb phrase, 3 "This is the place I live in." is wrong because adverb already includes preposition.
And yet, if we consider 'the place' in 3 as a noun phrase, then "This is the place I live in." is correct. The no. 3 is correct?

Who told you that (1) is correct? The place where I live or the place I live in/at. Place is a noun, not an adverb.

"the place I live"

Well, that discussion is decidedly ambivalent as to whether the place I live is acceptable or not! You don't 'live a place' or 'live a house'.

" To live there I would have to abandon the place I live now , and because I can't , I can't live there ."-
The Making of a Refugee
Children Adopting Refugee Identity in Cyprus
: Tasoulla Hadjiyanni · 2002
